# Magento Upgrade 1.5 to 1.7 - Dashboard Missing

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.5

I tried upgrading my magento from 1.5 to 1.7 and my database is now not showing. I followed a simple process:

1) Replicate database

2) Create new folder with Magento 1.7 files

3) I altered one line in config.xml as follows:

```
SET NAMES utf8

to this

SET NAMES utf8; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
```

I was following the suggestion of many others, in order to avoid getting Integrity Constraint violations during upgrade (which I had received on previous attempts).

4) I copied over extensions and themes from old installation to new installation

5) I ran the new Magento instance. I inserted database information for new database

6) I waited a very long time for magento to run database upgrades.

I came across two errors listed below. Error #1 disappeared after the first time:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:238:"Error in file: "/chroot/home/africanb/dev.mydomain.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/sql/customer_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.5.9.9-1.6.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0-1' for key 2";i:1;s:1196:"#0 /chroot/home/africanb/dev.mydomain.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /chroot/home/africanb/dev.mydomain.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '1.4.0.0.14', '1.6.2.0.1')
#2 /chroot/home/africanb/dev.mydomain.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('1.4.0.0.14', '1.6.2.0.1')
#3 /chroot/home/africanb/dev.mydomain.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /chroot/home/africanb/dev.mydomain.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /chroot/home/africanb/dev.mydomain.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /chroot/home/africanb/dev.mydomain.com/html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /chroot/home/africanb/dev.mydomain.com/html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:36:"/index.php/install/wizard/installDb/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Error #2 I had to remedy:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:264:"Error in file: "/chroot/home/africanb/dev.mydomain.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Reports/sql/reports_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.0-1.6.0.0.1.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily' already exists";i:1;s:1188:"#0 /chroot/home/africanb/dev.mydomain.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(645): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 /chroot/home/africanb/dev.mydomain.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('upgrade', '0.7.10', '1.6.0.0.1')
#2 /chroot/home/africanb/dev.mydomain.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_upgradeResourceDb('0.7.10', '1.6.0.0.1')
#3 /chroot/home/africanb/dev.mydomain.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 /chroot/home/africanb/dev.mydomain.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(417): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 /chroot/home/africanb/dev.mydomain.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 /chroot/home/africanb/dev.mydomain.com/html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /chroot/home/africanb/dev.mydomain.com/html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

In order to get passed error #2, i deleted three tables: report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily 
report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly 
report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly

Now, my dashboard is not showing. I basically have a blank page (below the Magento menu, and store chooser). I checked the error logs but could not find anything. I tried flushing cache and reindexing, but still no luck.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check the file permissions of dashboard-head.html to verify the server can read it.

Also please enable template path hints for the back-end and report what you see for the dashboard. Information on how to enable can be

found here: http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/quick-tip-template-hints-for-the-magento-admin-area/

And also for more to detail solution you can refer it [LINK](https://github.com/jirafe/magento-plugin/issues/41)

let me know if i can help you more.